# Rotate only the shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to rotate only the shape, keeping the anchors and text inside the same?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,preview,multi={tikzpicture},border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\def\hexagonosize{30mm}
\def\desloca{-\pgflinewidth}

\tikzset{%
    hexagono/.style={draw,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\hexagonosize,inner sep=0pt},
    hexagono2/.style={hexagono,rotate=90},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[hexagono] (centro) at (0,0) {};
\node[hexagono,anchor=150,yshift=\desloca*sin(330),xshift=\desloca*cos(330)] (A) at (centro.330) {A};
\node[hexagono,anchor=210,yshift=\desloca*sin(30),xshift=\desloca*cos(30)]   (B) at (centro.30)  {B};
\node[hexagono,anchor=270,yshift=\desloca] (C) at (centro.90)  {C};
\node[hexagono,anchor=330,yshift=\desloca*sin(150),xshift=\desloca*cos(150)] (D) at (centro.150) {D};
\node[hexagono,anchor=30,yshift=\desloca*sin(210),xshift=\desloca*cos(210)]  (E) at (centro.210) {E};
\node[hexagono,anchor=90,yshift=-\desloca] (F) at (centro.270) {F};

\draw[thick] (A.90) -- (F.45);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[hexagono2] (centro) at (0,0) {};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=150,yshift=\desloca*sin(330),xshift=\desloca*cos(330)] (A) at (centro.330) {A};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=210,yshift=\desloca*sin(30),xshift=\desloca*cos(30)]   (B) at (centro.30)  {B};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=270,yshift=\desloca] (C) at (centro.90)  {C};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=330,yshift=\desloca*sin(150),xshift=\desloca*cos(150)] (D) at (centro.150) {D};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=30,yshift=\desloca*sin(210),xshift=\desloca*cos(210)]  (E) at (centro.210) {E};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=90,yshift=-\desloca] (F) at (centro.270) {F};

\draw[thick] (A.90) -- (F.45);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `shape border rotate` option?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I does not work work. Gives something strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will use the `shape border rotate` option as suggested in a comment by @Claudio Fiandrino.

First of all lets have a look at the anchors. The right picture is the rotated hexagon. Note that c1 means the anchor `corner 1` and s1 means the anchor `side 1`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand\hexagonosize{30mm}
\tikzset{%
    hexagono/.style={draw,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\hexagonosize,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
    hexagono2/.style={hexagono,shape border rotate=90},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
  \node[hexagono](test){T};
  \foreach \i/\l in {1/above,2/left}{
    \node[blue,label={[blue]\l:c\i}] at (test.corner \i){x};
    \node[blue,label={[blue]\l:s\i}] at (test.side \i){x};
  }
  \foreach \i/\l in {0/right,300/left}\node[green,label={[green]right:\i}] at (test.\i){x};
  \node[green,label={[green]below:south}]at(test.south){x};
%
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
  \node[hexagono2](test){T};
  \foreach \i/\l in {1/left,2/below left}{
    \node[blue,label={[blue]\l:c\i}] at (test.corner \i){x};
    \node[blue,label={[blue]\l:s\i}] at (test.side \i){x};
  }
  \foreach \i/\l in {0/right,300/left}\node[green,label={[green]right:\i}] at (test.\i){x};
  \node[green,label={[green]below:south}]at(test.south){x};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the compass and the angle anchors are not rotated if `shape border rotate` is used. Only the geometric anchors like `corner 1` and `side 1` are rotated.

But you can also see that other angle anchors must be used to position the outer hexagons around the center:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand\hexagonosize{30mm}
\tikzset{%
    hexagono/.style={draw,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\hexagonosize,
                     inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
    hexagono2/.style={hexagono,shape border rotate=90},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[hexagono] (centro) at (0,0) {};
\node[hexagono,anchor=150] (A) at (centro.330) {A};
\node[hexagono,anchor=210] (B) at (centro.30)  {B};
\node[hexagono,anchor=270] (C) at (centro.90)  {C};
\node[hexagono,anchor=330] (D) at (centro.150) {D};
\node[hexagono,anchor=30]  (E) at (centro.210) {E};
\node[hexagono,anchor=90]  (F) at (centro.270) {F};
\draw[thick,orange] (A.90) -- (F.45);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[hexagono2] (centro) at (0,0) {};
\node[hexagono2] (centro) at (0,0) {};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=180] (A) at (centro.0)   {A};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=240] (B) at (centro.60)  {B};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=300] (C) at (centro.120) {C};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=0]   (D) at (centro.180) {D};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=60]  (E) at (centro.240) {E};
\node[hexagono2,anchor=120] (F) at (centro.300) {F};

\draw[thick,orange] (A.90) -- (F.45);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I have used `outer sep=0pt` for `hexagono` style.

---

But I suggest to use the `side 1`,...,`side 6` anchors to place the hexagons. Then it is possible to use different rotation angles:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand\hexagonosize{30mm}
\tikzset{%
    hexagono/.style={draw,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\hexagonosize,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,shape border rotate=#1},
    hexagono/.default={0},
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \rotangle in {0,45,90,200}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[hexagono=\rotangle](centro) at (0,0) {};
    \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\j=int(\i<=3?\i+3:\i-3)}] \n in {C,D,E,F,A,B}
      \node[hexagono=\rotangle,anchor=side \j](\n)at(centro.side \i){\n};
  \draw[orange,thick] (A.90) -- (F.45);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

---

If node `A` should be positioned right of `centro` you have to manually choose the node anchored on `centro.side 1`. For 0° and 45° it is `C` (3th node in the node name Array - see code below), for 90° it is `D` (4th node) and for 200° it is `F` (6th node).

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand\hexagonosize{30mm}
\tikzset{%
    hexagono/.style={draw,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\hexagonosize,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,shape border rotate=#1},
    hexagono/.default={0},
}

\newcommand\hexagons{{"A","B","C","D","E","F"}}% pgfarray with the node names

\begin{document}
\foreach \rotangle/\start in {0/3,45/3,90/4,200/6}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[hexagono=\rotangle](centro) at (0,0) {};
    %\node[font=\tiny]at(centro.side 1){x};% to mark the side 1 anchor of centro
    \foreach[
      evaluate={\j=int(\i<=3?\i+3:\i-3)},
      evaluate={\n=\hexagons[int(\start+\i-1<=6?\start+\i-2:\start+\i-8)]},
      ] \i in {1,...,6}
      \node[hexagono=\rotangle,anchor=side \j](\n)at(centro.side \i){\n};
  \draw[thick,orange] (A.90) -- (F.45);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update: Using the angle anchors**

There is also a possibility to use the angle anchors in the same way. You only have to know on which angle anchor `\posA` of the `centro` node the node must be positioned:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand\hexagonosize{30mm}
\tikzset{%
    hexagono/.style={draw,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\hexagonosize,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,shape border rotate=#1},
    hexagono/.default={0},
}

\newcommand\hexagons{{"A","B","C","D","E","F"}}% pgfarray with the node names

\begin{document}

\foreach \rotangle/\posA in {0/-30,45/15,90/0,200/-10}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[hexagono=\rotangle] (centro) at (0,0) {};
    \foreach[
        evaluate={\pos=\posA+\i*60},
        evaluate={\anc=\pos+180},
        evaluate={\n=\hexagons[\i]}
      ]\i in {0,...,5}
      \node[hexagono=\rotangle,anchor=\anc] (\n) at (centro.\pos)  {\n};
      \draw[thick,orange] (A.90) -- (F.45);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above. But now you can also use your `\desloca` instead of `outersep=0pt`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand\hexagonosize{30mm}
\tikzset{%
    hexagono/.style={draw,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=\hexagonosize,
        inner sep=0pt,
        %outer sep=0pt,% do not use together with \desloca
        shape border rotate=#1},
    hexagono/.default={0},
}

\newcommand\desloca{-\pgflinewidth}

\newcommand\hexagons{{"A","B","C","D","E","F"}}% pgfarray with the node names

\begin{document}

\foreach \rotangle/\posA in {0/-30,45/15,90/0,200/-10}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[hexagono=\rotangle] (centro) at (0,0) {};
    \foreach[
        evaluate={\pos=\posA+\i*60},
        evaluate={\anc=\pos+180},
        evaluate={\n=\hexagons[\i]}
      ]\i in {0,...,5}
      \node[hexagono=\rotangle,anchor=\anc,yshift=\desloca*sin(\pos),xshift=\desloca*cos(\pos)] (\n) at (centro.\pos)  {\n};
      \draw[thick,purple] (A.90) -- (F.45);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the result is again the same:

[image]

Comment: With your solution how can I add the minor correction that I call `\desloca`?

Comment: I have added an example with the `\desloca` at the end. Note, in the other examples I use `outer sep=0pt` for the nodes to get the same result. In addition I have changed the used angle anchors in the first example. So you can add there `\desloca` in the same way as in your code example. In that case you have to remove `outer sep=0pt`.